# How to refresh access token in C#

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-core, token, restsharp

I can't find a tutorial or a code example where it shows how/when to refresh the access token. How to implement refreshing the new access token when it is about to expire?

This is what I have so far:

This is the class where to get the new access token and refresh token.

```
namespace DemoApp
{
    public class Tokens
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccessToken 
    {
        public void GetNewAccessToken()
        {
            Tokens localTokens = new Tokens();

            var client = new RestClient("www.example.com/api/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + localTokens.refresh_token, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var responseContent = response.Content;

            var newTokensList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Tokens>(responseContent);

            localTokens.access_token = newTokensList .access_token;
            localTokens.refresh_token = newTokensList .refresh_token;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class where it call the API, with the new Access Token, to get the new data.

```
namespace DemoApp
{
    public class API
    {
        public Data()
        {
            public void CallAPI()
            {
                Tokens tokens = new Tokens();
                var client = new RestClient("www.example.com/api");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + tokens.access_token);
                request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                var data = response.Content;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a common practice in OAuth2, to issue a refresh token every time you issue an access token, and then if your access token expires (you get 401), you get new one with refresh token. If you are using Identity Server 4, then their documentation is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Aspram I am having problem with when to refresh the access token. So you saying that when I call the API (to get data), if I receive an error 401, then I should call the GetNewAccessToken and then recall the API again?
No I don't use Identity Server.

Comment: Yes that is a common practice in OAuth 2. You can have a timer in your client or something like that, to refresh it right before your expires_in time finishes, but the best practice, is to refresh it by handling 401(unauthorized) error.